# Flutter Inapp Purchase

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have been playing around with the flutter_inapp_purchase package and it seems straight forward. I am able to connect, get available items for purchase, and buy a product, but I can't quite figure out how to check to see if the user has already purchased the item. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue and am replying in case anyone else has this problem. It ended up being pretty simple in the end.

**By calling:**

```
List purchaseditem = await FlutterInappPurchase.getAvailablePurchases();
```

Check the list for the `productID` in question, if it exists return true.